# Fast texel settting in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, rendering, artificial-intelligence, textures

I'm in need of rendering an influence map in OpenGL. At present I have 100 x 100 quads rendering with a set color to represent the influence at each point on the map. I've been recommended to change my rendering method to one quad with a texture, then allowing the rendering pipeline to take over in speed.

Basic testing has shown that glTexSubImage2D is too slow for setting 10,000 texels per frame. Do you have any suggestions? Would it better to create an entirely new texture each frame? My influence map is in normalized floats (0.0 to 1.0) and that is converted to grayscale colors (1.0f = white).

Thanks :D

Comment: Are you calling `glTexSubImage2D()` 10000 times to update 10000 texels, or once to update 10000 texels?

Comment: Why is this tagged artificial-intelligence?

Comment: It's tagged AI because the technique is an influence map. I figured it being AI might attract someone who would tell me I'm doing it wrong and shed experience on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you currently updating each of the 10000 texels separately, with 10000 calls of glTexSubImage2D?

Just use one 100x100 grayscale float texture (array of 10000 floats) in RAM, update values directly to that and then send the whole data to GPU with one glTexImage2D call. You could also use buffer objects to allow the transfer happen on background, but it should be unnecessary since you are not moving very large amounts of data.

Comment: It appears to have done the trick. I was doing 10,000 calls to glTexSubImage2D but it was evidently poor. Keeping the entire thing in RAM before sending a new texture with glTexImage2D did the job much better. Thanks